# Get serial numbers for installed software

Tags: sccm

Is it possible to get serial numbers from installed software (Adobe, Autodesk, VMWare etc.)?

From WMI I can get only MS keys - OS/Office. Is there any way to receive it from `SCCM` or `AD`?

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple way that I know of. It would depend on each application, if you're lucky and they store the information in the registry then you can add that to software inventory, but if it's in an encrypted key file (as I suspect Adobe uses) then you're pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For non `REG-BINARY` type I use this script which reads information from `csv` file. So I don't need any decode manipulations.

```
    $csv = Import-CSV "\\fs-lv-01\users$\username\Desktop\PowerShell\TSTArray.csv"
    $resultsarray = @()

    $target = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    $hklm = "HKLM:"
    $join_path = $hklm, $regPath -join "\"

    Foreach ($Registry in $csv)
    {
                    $regPath = $Registry.regPath
                    $regValue = $Registry.regValue
                    $join_path = $hklm, $regPath -join "\"

        If ($Registry.regPath -ne 0)
        {
            $data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $join_path -name $regValue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).$regValue 

            IF ($data -ne $null)
            {
                $obj = New-Object Object
                $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Computer -value $target
                $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty ProductKey -value $data
                $obj

                $resultsarray += $obj
            }
        }

    }

    $resultsarray | Export-Csv "\\fs-lv-01\users$\username\Desktop\PowerShell\TSTSerialNumbers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The same idea for `Microsoft` products:

```
$csv = Import-CSV "\\fs-lv-01\users$\username\Desktop\PowerShell\MSArray.csv"
$resultsarray = @()

$hklm = 2147483650
$target = $env:COMPUTERNAME

Foreach ($Registry in $csv)
{
                $regPath = $Registry.regPath
                $regValue = $Computer_name.regValue

    If ($Registry.regPath -ne 0)
    {
        $productKey = $null
        $win32os = $null
        $wmi = [WMIClass]"\\$target\root\default:stdRegProv"
        $data = $wmi.GetBinaryValue($hklm,$regPath,$regValue)
        $binArray = ($data.uValue)[52..66]
        $charsArray = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
        ## decrypt base24 encoded binary data
        for ($i = 24; $i -ge 0; $i--) { 
                      $r = 0 
                      for ($j = 14; $j -ge 0; $j--) { 
                        $r = ($r * 256) -bxor $binArray[$j] 
                        $binArray[$j] = [math]::Floor([double]($r/24)) 
                        $r = $r % 24 
                      } 
                      $ProductKey = $charsArray[$r] + $ProductKey 
                      if (($i % 5) -eq 0 -and $i -ne 0) { 
                        $ProductKey = "-" + $ProductKey 
                      } 
                    }
        $win32os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $target
        $obj = New-Object Object
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Computer -value $target
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Caption -value $win32os.Caption
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty OSArch -value $win32os.OSArchitecture
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty ProductKey -value $productKey
        $obj

        $resultsarray += $obj

    }

}

$resultsarray | Export-Csv "\\fs-lv-01\users$\username\Desktop\PowerShell\SerialNumbers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Both scripts are tested, but I want also to get `Adobe` keys.. I have information about how to decode `Adobe` serials, but I need to test it on licensed version.